# Select Query with userlogin and password

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want to retrive the table information from other server database.

Query like 'Server2

I already linked the server

```
Select * from server2.database1.dbo.table1
```

It's showing `login failed for user sa`

Any other alternative query for passing the password in select query..?

like

```
Select * from server2.database1.dbo.table 'sa'
```

Any help suggestion...?

Comment: At time of linking itself you should provide username and password of database. No need to specify by query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linked server - there is no any alternative, but you may use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) function which accepts server/user/password

Answer (score 2):

I think the username/password is specified for your linked server when you set up the link. Once you issue a query against the linked server, that username/password will be used. Make sure that the account you used to set up the link has access to the data source of your database.

You can also try using OPENDATASOURCE to access the remote server, although if I remember correctly, it's slower than using a linker server. It does take a username/password parameter so you'd be specifying those in your SELECT query.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) has some examples on how to use it.